# How to automatically parenthesize arbitrary haskell expressions?

Tags: haskell

I'm learning haskell, and I have a lot of difficulty with mentally parsing many haskell expressions I come across.

Of course, I expect that, with enough practice, mentally parsing haskell will become second-nature, but in the meantime, in order to make sense of what I come across, I'd like to find some automatic way to translate an arbitrary "standard haskell"<sup>1</sup> expression into one in which all "ambiguous"<sup>2</sup> sub-expressions have been eliminated by introducing the necessary parentheses.

For example, it would translate the expression

```
f g h i
```

...into

```
((f g) h) i
```

..., or

```
a -> b -> c -> d
```

...into

```
a -> (b -> (c -> d))
```

..., etc.

Preferably, this would be a tool I can access with my phone, since I do much of my reading on haskell away from a proper computer.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Of course, no such tool could possibly work with custom operators of unknown fixity and associativity.  By "standard haskell" I mean the stuff defined in the prelude and in the standard haskell library.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup>I'm using "ambiguous" here as shorthand for "ambiguous in the absence of precedence rules".  E.g. `2 + 3 * 5` is ambiguous *unless* there's some precedence rule that settles the question of which of the two operations will be performed first.</sup>

Comment: I can`t think of anything on your _phone_, but there are some pretty straightforward things you can do in GHCi

Comment: Well, [haskell-src-exts](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts-1.18.2/docs/Language-Haskell-Exts.html) makes it easy to get a completely unambiguous parse tree and print it out. But it ain't really readable. Try `(fmap . fmap . fmap) (const ()) (parseFile "foo.hs")` from ghci once you've installed it.

Comment: @Alec: what exactly can I do in ghci?  (about the phone: that was just a preference, and a mild one at that, in case there was a choice in the matter; if there isn't, i'll gladly settle for ghci.)

Comment: [This brand new tool](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/describe#describe) seems to do exactly what you describe in the term level.

Comment: Thank you for the heads-up!  It looks like a godsend for the haskell noob (like me).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you really want to go to the work of it, you could write a [`TemplateHaskell`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.11.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH.html) function to do this for you - you essentially just walk the AST and add parens at will. I started doing that, but realized it will get pretty long and tedious pretty fast. I think it may be more convenient for the moment for you to only think about currying when it actually comes into play (with functions that are not fully applied).

---

However, there is a trick you can use for a subcase of your problem: *parens around operators whose fixity and associativity you aren't familiar with*. In GHCi, after booting up with the right flags, just wrap the expression you are interested in inspecting in `$([| <expression> |])`. Then, you get to see a parenthesized version of your expression before the result of evaluating it.

```
$ ghci -ddump-splices -XTemplateHaskell
Prelude> $([| 1 + 2 ^ 3 * 4 |])
<interactive>:1:3-21: Splicing expression
    [| 1 + 2 ^ 3 * 4 |] ======> (1 + ((2 ^ 3) * 4))
33
Prelude> $([| 1 <$ pure 4 >>= \x -> const mempty =<< [(+),(*)] <*> [1,2] <* [False] |])
<interactive>:2:3-77: Splicing expression
    [| 1 <$ pure 4
       >>=
         (\ x_a6PT -> const mempty =<< [(+), (*)] <*> [1, 2] <* [False] |]
  ======>
    ((1 <$ (pure 4))
     >>=
       (\ x_a6PT
          -> ((const mempty) =<< (([(+),(*)] <*> [1,2]) <* [False]))))
[]
Prelude>
```

However, this definitely won't fix the type signatures or function applications the way you want.

Answer (score 4):

It's not exactly what you're asking for, but I've found using [HLint](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hlint) to warn me about unnecessary parens when I'm *writing* Haskell to be a big help when I'm *reading*.

You may also find the chart on page 23 of [Bernie Pope's "A tour of the Haskell Prelude"](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/year/2015/course/TDA452/Haskell-Prelude-Tour-A4.pdf) helpful. I've included a copy below.

[image: page 23 of Bernie Pope's "A tour of the Haskell Prelude"]