# Monad Challenges: No instance for MonadState

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

I'm new to Haskell and trying my hand at [the monad challenges](http://mightybyte.github.io/monad-challenges/pages/set1.html). The following code gives an error message:

```
type Rand a = StateT Seed Identity a    

hi :: Rand Integer
hi = get >>= \std -> (put . snd $ rand std) >> return . fst $ rand std
-- hi = state rand

main = print $ product . fst $ runState (replicateM 5 hi) (mkSeed 1)


No instance for (MonadState Seed ((->) (Integer, Seed)))
      arising from a use of ‘put’
    In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘put’
    In the expression: put . snd
    In the first argument of ‘(>>)’, namely ‘(put . snd $ rand std)’
```

While the code below runs fine, even though it should be the same thing.

```
hi = get >>= \std -> (put . snd $ rand std) >>= \_ -> return . fst $ rand std
```

Can someone explain why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Likely useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331179/how-to-automatically-parenthesize-arbitrary-haskell-expressions/40333460#40333460

Comment: oh I get it, thanks

Comment: Does the problem fixes itself one you add some parentheses in the "right" places?