# Unexpected Result When a Monoid on Arrows is Applied

Tags: haskell, arrows

I have this simple "arrows":

```
main = do
        let
        -- arr :: (Arrow a) => (b -> c) -> a b c
        -- (>>>) :: Category cat => cat a b -> cat b c -> cat a c
        -- (<+>) :: ArrowPlus a => a b c -> a b c -> a b c
        -- infixr 5 <+>
        -- infixr 1 >>>
        -- runKleisli :: Kleisli m a b -> a -> m b
          prepend x = arr (x ++)
          append  x = arr (++ x)

          xform = (prepend "<") >>> (append ">") <+> (prepend "{") >>> (append "}")
          xs = ["foobar"] >>= (runKleisli xform)
        mapM_ putStrLn xs
```

The `<+>` returns:

```
<foobar>}
{<foobar}
```

and if I replace the `xform` with:

```
xform = ((prepend "<") >>> (append ">")) <+> ((prepend "{") >>> (append "}"))
```

I get:

```
<foobar>
{foobar}
```

Why I get these 2 results? Even looking at `infixr`s (as comments in the code) doesn't really help.

Comment: [This will probably get you the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331179/how-to-automatically-parenthesize-arbitrary-haskell-expressions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets write that a bit more to the point:

```
xform = prepend "<" >>> append ">" <+> prepend "<" >>> append ">"
xform' = (prepend "<" >>> append ">") <+> (prepend "<" >>> append ">")
```

Now `xform`, because `infixr 5 <+>` binds more tightly than `infixl 1 >>>`, is parsed as

```
xform = prepend "<" >>> (append ">" <+> prepend "<") >>> append ">"
```

which as a diagram reads

```
                           ┌─append ">"──┐
     ──────prepend "<"─────<             +>═══append ">"═════▶
                           └─prepend "<"─┘
```

whereas `xform'` corresponds simply to

```
            ┌─prepend "<"──append ">"─┐
     ───────<                         +>════▶
            └─prepend "<"──append ">"─┘
```

That should explain it.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear from your question what you were expecting it to do.  If this answer still doesn't help, writing what you expect your code to do will help us understand how you're thinking.

The arrow you are working with is `Kleisli []` -- that is, the arrow built on the list monad.  The list as a monad is a nondeterminism abstraction -- that is, lists behave like collections of possibilities.

The `Kliesli [] a b` type is equivalent to `a -> [b]`, treated as a monadic function, that is: it takes a single input and returns many possible outputs.

What `<+>` does is transform the input by each of its arguments, then take the union of the possibilities.  So if you run the arrow:

```
arr id <+> arr reverse
```

with the input `"hello"`, then you will get two answers:

```
hello
olleh
```

If you compose it with anything, each possibility will be composed:

```
prepend "<" >>> (arr id <+> arr reverse)
```

then you'll get

```
<hello
olleh<
```

so each alternative of `<+>` is being considered "in parallel".  The reason the `<` comes at the of the second line is because the input `arr reverse` is getting has already had `"<"` prepended.  By contrast, if you did

```
(arr id <+> arr reverse) >>> prepend "<"
```

Then you get

```
<hello
<olleh
```

Is this making sense why you get the output you did now?

Comment: Thank you for your answer which is very clear. The graphs by @leftaroundabout clarified a lot too.