# Why list monad combines in that order?

Tags: list, haskell, syntax, monads, parentheses

I was reading about list monads and encountered:

```
[1,2] >>= \n -> ['a','b'] >>= \ch -> return (n,ch)
```

it produces

```
[(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'a'),(2,'b')]
```

Here's how I understand it:

Implicit parentheses are:

```
([1,2] >>= \n -> ['a','b']) >>= (\ch -> return (n,ch))
```

`([1,2] >>= \n -> ['a','b'])` should give `[('a',1),('b',1),('a',2),('b',2)]`

because

```
instance Monad [] where  
  return x = [x]  
  xs >>= f = concat (map f xs)   -- this line
  fail _ = []
```

so `concat (map f xs)` is `concat (map (\n -> ['a','b']) [1,2])` which should produce `[('a',1),('b',1),('a',2),('b',2)]` - quite the opposite of the actual output.

Then I don't understand `>>= (\ch -> return (n,ch))` part - I think that `n` here has no sense. That specific reasoning is flawed, could you please explain how that expression(`[1,2] >>= \n -> ['a','b'] >>= \ch -> return (n,ch)`) is computed step-by-step?

Comment: note that `[1, 2] >>= \n -> ['a', 'b'] == "abab"`, not `[('a',1),('b',1),('a',2),('b',2)]`.

Comment: No, it's `[1,2] >>= (\n -> ['a','b'] >>= (\ch -> return (n,ch)))`

Comment: You may be interested in ["How to automatically parenthesize arbitrary haskell expressions?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40331179/3072788)

Comment: an interesting tidbit: for lists `join == concat` and `map == fmap`, so `f =<< xs = concat (map f xs) == join (fmap f xs)`, as it indeed [should be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11249714/849891) (check out other answers there as well). :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your implicit parentheses are wrong.  The way you have it, the `n` parameter to the first lambda would not be in scope in the `return`.  It is more like:

```
([1,2] >>= (\n -> ['a','b'] >>= (\ch -> return (n,ch))))
```

Which becomes:

```
concatMap (\n -> concatMap (\ch -> [(n,ch)]) ['a','b']) [1,2]
```

Comment: That last line I was seeking.

Answer (score 4):

No, you're using wrong parenthesization. It's nested to the right, so that

```
[1,2] >>= \n -> ['a','b'] >>= \ch -> return (n,ch)  
=
[1,2] >>= (\n -> ['a','b'] >>= (\ch -> return (n,ch) ))
=
do { n <- [1,2]
   ; do { ch <- ['a','b']
        ; return (n,ch) }}
=
for n in [1,2]:              -- pseudocode
    for ch in ['a','b']:
        return (n,ch)
=
[ r | n <- [1,2], ch <- ['a','b'], r <- [(n,ch)] ]    -- return == (:[])
=
[ (n,ch) | n <- [1,2], ch <- ['a','b'] ]
=
pure (,) <*> [1,2] <*> ['a','b']      -- using list applicative
=
[(1,'a'), (1,'b'), (2,'a'), (2,'b')]
```

and the innermost list is "spinning" the fastest, like in a car's odometer.

You are absolutely right, with the wrong parenthesization the `n` binding would make no sense. It is precisely for that reason that it *must* associate to the right, to make the nested binding possible; for the *nested computations* are the *essence* of the monad:

```
[ foo x   | x <- xs ]           -- functor : amendable computations
[ bar x y | x <- xs AND y <- ys ]     -- applicative : combinable computations
[ baz x y | x <- xs, y <- foo x ]         -- monad : reinterpretative computations
```

(and yes, omitting parentheses in learning material is the root of all evil... not really, but still...)

Answer (score 3):

> Implicit parentheses are:
>
> ```
> ([1,2] >>= \n -> ['a','b']) >>= (\ch -> return (n,ch))
> ```

This is wrong. `\` has  the lowest precedence and thus extends to the end of the expression. So the parentheses are:

```
[1,2] >>= (\n -> ['a','b'] >>= (\ch -> return (n,ch)))
```

> `([1,2] >>= \n -> ['a','b'])` should give `[('a',1),('b',1),('a',2),('b',2)]`

As you can see from the above parenthesization `([1,2] >>= \n -> ['a','b'])`, isn't actually a subexpression of the given expression. But if it were, its result would be `['a', 'b', 'a', 'b']`. `n` is not actually used anywhere in the expressions `['a', 'b']`, so there's no way the numbers could appear in the result.

> Then I don't understand >>= (\ch -> return (n,ch)) part - I think that n here has no sense.

Given your parenthesization `n` would indeed be undefined there. However given the proper parenthesization it should be clear where `n` comes from: We're still inside the `\n -> ...` function, so `n` still refers to the argument of that function, namely the current element of the `[1, 2]` list.

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong about the semantics of `concat (map (\n -> ['a','b']) [1,2])`. I've done a step by step evaluation of it below.

`concat (map (\n -> ['a','b']) [1,2])`

`concat [(\n -> ['a','b']) 1, (\n -> ['a','b']) 2]`

`concat [['a','b'], ['a','b']]`

`['a','b','a','b']`

The last bind is what is used to actually make it a list of tuples.

Comment: answers above told me that this order of parentheses is wrong, so your evaluation is not relevant. Thanks. anyway.