# Calling Map.mapWithKey with input function that return a Monad type

Tags: haskell, monads

I have a function

```
type Reducer k v = k -> [v] -> [v]
```

If I have a variable `r` from type

```
Ord k =>  Reducer k v
```

and a variable `input`  from type

```
 Ord k =>  Map k [v]
```

I can write the expression

```
Map.toList . Map.mapWithKey r input
```

and get an output from type `[(k,[v])]`

Now say I have a function from type :

```
type ReducerM m k v = k -> [v] -> m [v]
```

and a variable `rm` from type :

```
(Ord k, Monad m) => ReducerM m k v
```

I want to apply the expression

```
Map.toList . Map.mapWithKey rm input
```

and get back a type  `m [(k,[v])]`

Can someone help guide me how to do that ?

Comment: You can use `pure :: Applicative m => a -> m a`.

Comment: Thanks you - could you be more specific ?  What  expression  Map.toList . Map.mapWithKey rm input  will be converted to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your reducer results through `fmap (k ,)`

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

fmap (k ,) (_ :: m [v]) :: m (k,[v])
```

then `toList` gives you `[m (k,[v])]`.

Then `sequence` turns that into `m [(k,[v])]` that you wanted.

Comment: Thanks you could you help me write this expression ? I'm not familiar with Haskell to the level to understand you answer.

Comment: instead of calling `Map.mapWithKey r input` you call `Map.mapWithKey foo input` where `foo k vs = let {temp1 = r k vs ; temp2 = ... } in temp2`.  we have `r :: k->[v]->m [v]`, `k :: k`, `vs :: [v]`. what type is `temp1`? you want the result type to be `m (k,[v])`. Can you create `temp2 :: m (k,[v])` based on what you see in the answer? ( `(k ,)` is the same as `(\x -> (k, x))` if you prefer it). if you can, then you pass the result to `toList` (with `$` , not with `.`), and pass the result of that to `sequence`. ("pass the result X to F" == "call F with X as argument, like `F X` or `F $ X`").

Comment: but if you find it difficult, maybe you should redo your previous exercises.

Comment: Thank you I'll try that. What do you think about just using traverseWithKey instead of mapWithKey ?

Comment: looks like it'll do the job for you. :) `sequence` is old Haskell; `sequenceA` / `traverse` is more modern.

Comment: Even without traverseWithKey. Looks to me that I can do sequenceA   $ Map.mapWithKey r input and it is just working!

Comment: not `r` though. you wanted the paring with the `k`. your `r` produces `m [v]`, it needs to be [amended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47397690/849891), with `fmap`. also, `sequence _after_ map` is how `traverse / mapM` is defined (up to the `A`)